# Rails Koala - Updating Oauth_token for a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, koala

Hey guys apologizes for the beginner's question, still learning rails. I was able to set up facebook authentication using omniauth and devise perfectly. Now, I'm starting to play with the Koala gem.

Once I added a line for oauth_token to my user model, any new user who signs up with Facebook - I can connect with their Facebook api and get their data. But, I've got a problem with my old users (who signed up prior to me installing Koala) and who have their oauth_token set to nil. How can I update oauth_token for them so that I can connect with the facebook api just like the new users? I have listed my relevant code below. Thank you so much!

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = auth.info.name     
      user.avatar = URI.parse(auth.info.image)
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token #Added this after learning about Koala
    end
  end

  def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.oauth_token)
  end
end
```

**After User Logs in Again - it still keeps oauth_token to nil**
[image]

Comment: Have you handled how to update the token when the token is no longer valid? If not it might be a good idea to do that and upon logging in you could check for that potential workflow and execute that workflow if it is null or about to expire.

Comment: Tall, thank you so much for responding. I haven't learned how to update the token when the token is no longer valid. How may I go about doing that?